# Lotus Notes 8.5.2 Cannot Attach

Tags: lotus-notes, attachments

Being quite versed in research and troubleshooting I am confused by this one.

System: Dell Latitude D630, XPSP3

I cannot drag files to an email message without getting an hourglass (does not attach) but allows me to use notes as if nothing happens.  I can even shut down notes (with 2 processes that do not shut down in the background and have to use killnotes).

I cannot attach a file either, it either gives me an error note/reporting screen and shuts down.

What I have tried:  Reinstalling, deleting/renaming cache.ndk, deleting/renaming desktop. file, deleting the %temp% file.

None of these have fixed the issue.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you attach files to email messages by locating your cursor in the message body and selecting Attach from the File menu?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried that.  Reacts the same way as when I click the paperclip icon, just sends up the Lotus Notes box "an error has occurred" then sends error report.  Doesn't usually show that box when I drag and drop, just hourglasses infinitely, but can still use notes.  (I can even shutdown, etc. but still need to run killnotes to kill leftover processes dealing with attachment)

Comment: Is an NSD file created in the IBM_Technical_Support folder (inside the Notes\Data folder)?

Comment: is the file coming for a network share or the local harddrive?  if you are able to 'pause' your antivirus, you might also try that.

Comment: Zach:  I can (sometimes) pause realtime protection on Symantec Endpoint protection but cannot at the moment.  I am pulling only local files, nothing networked

Comment: rhsatrhs:  I have .log files titled NSD.  Other ext are .txt, .adr, .bat, .inventory, .txt, .dmp, and a smartupgrade folder.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. You have to edit your notes.ini file and remove ExtMgr_Addins=zmAuto or ExtMgr_Addins=ZMAuto,ZMFiltr if they appear.  I removed an instance of ZMAuto and it fixed the issue.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Just a wild guess based on the filenames of the addins: you have ZipMail for Notes installed?

Comment: @Jason, if you have solved the problem, you can post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted, which will help anyone who has the same problem in the future.